# Image flowing out of parent div container how come it is hidden?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

So I basically have these project cards and I'm using materialize css's image card to help me style.
I love how it is able to resize the picture because I'm including it inside the  this allows me to set a fixed height and not worry about the image resolution looking like crap.

I'm just wondering how the image is able to overflow outside the container but isn't getting shown outside? I want to learn this for the future as I hate sizing pictures responsivity and trying to get them to stay in line...

Here is an image of [overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQF3T.png)

```html
 <div class='row'>
            <div class="project-card col s12 m12 l4">
                <div class="card hoverable large">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img class='project-img' src="images/drake.PNG" alt="project1">
                        <span class="card-title" style="width:100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">Drake API</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='project-link'> 
                        <a href='https://github.com/Jay-Trades/Drake-API'>Project</a> 
                        <a href='https://github.com/Jay-Trades/Drake-API'>Code</a>    
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card col s12 m12 l4">
                <div class="edit card hoverable large">
                    <div class="card-image">
                      <img class='project-img' src="images/dogmeet.png" alt="project1">
                        <span class="card-title" style="width:100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">Dog Meet</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='project-link'> 
                        <a href='https://jay-trades.github.io/Dog-Meet/'>Project</a> 
                        <a href='https://github.com/Jay-Trades/Dog-Meet'>Code</a>      
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out how this is possible is to rightclick on the img and choose 'inspect element'. Then you can see the css styles for the img and its containers (like overflow: hidden; etc.). An other way would be to dig in the code of materialize.js and materialize.css – but for me would that be far to complex...